# Architecture ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

I am starting with ASP MVC and I have a doubt. I need a function class with different functions (example: SendEmail()). Where is would be located (folder) this file considering that they are generic functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, I create a folder a name it something like "Utils" or "Helpers" and put there all the stuff that isn't controller or model related. Create it on the same level as the Controller folder, for example, and you can use it anyway you wish

Comment: That's what I thought, but i'm not sure if it is correct for this type of architecture.

Comment: @Karedel, the MVC architecture that's immutable consists, basically, of the Model, View and Controller folders. For any other classes that contain whatever, they can be placed anywhere in the project, or in a parallel project, or in a library, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want to. It's based on the architecture of the project. Just not create it in any of application folders:

- App_Data Folder
- Content Folder
- Controllers Folder
- Models Folder
- Scripts Folder
- Views Folder

For example: create "Auxiliary" folder in root.